# Reversing Qt application

Tags: gdb, qt

I want to reverse-engineer a Qt crackme written for linux. I would like to follow where introduced text gets. I have found [this](http://silmor.de/qtstuff.printqstring.php) `gdb` macro to print QStrings (Qt5). To test it I wrote a simple helloworld application containing:

```
QString str("almafa");
qDebug() << str;
```

This prints the QString as expected.

```
(gdb) printqs5static str
(Qt5 QString)0xffffdf50 length=6: "almafa"
```

After this I tried to inspect QStrings where no variable names are present.

The compiled code looks like (in `radare2`):

```
|           0x00400ab7      488d45b0       leaq -0x50(%rbp), %rax
|           0x00400abb      488d55c0       leaq -0x40(%rbp), %rdx
|           0x00400abf      4889d6         movq %rdx, %rsi
|           0x00400ac2      4889c7         movq %rax, %rdi
|           0x00400ac5      e816feffff     callq sym.QMessageLogger::debug
|           0x00400aca      488d55a0       leaq -0x60(%rbp), %rdx
|           0x00400ace      488d45b0       leaq -0x50(%rbp), %rax
|           0x00400ad2      4889d6         movq %rdx, %rsi
|           0x00400ad5      4889c7         movq %rax, %rdi
|           0x00400ad8      e863020000     callq sym.QDebug::operator__
```

I do not have experience debugging Qt applications, but I expected that from the above code snippet that at `0x400ad8` either `rsi` or `rdi` will be the QString. Unfortunately `printqs5static $rsi` is not working. `i r $rsi` gives `0x7ffffffdf50`, the address from `printqs5static str` result.

The question is how to inspect QStrings when only memory addresses are available?

Edit: The web page I am referring is down at this moment, but a cashed version is [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://silmor.de/qtstuff.printqstring.php).
[`gdb`pretty printers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492290/gdb-pretty-printers-for-qt5)  are also able to print QStrings if there are symbolic names available. Still do not know how to work without them.

Comment: I'd take a look at the following related question: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/hints-to-reverse-engineering-a-qt-software

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `printqs5static $rdi`? Assuming that call goes to the function with the prototype `QDebug & QDebug::operator<<(const QString & s)`, then it's `rdi` that should contain the `QString`, not RSI.

Another option is to dump memory around `rdi` and `rsi`. I doubt the object is super complicated, so there should be a pointer to a normal C string nearby.