# Recovering variable name in debugger

Tags: gdb

This question somehow relates to my previous [question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11990/reversing-qt-application), but now I have a binary which is not stripped.

Let's say I have the following code snippet

```
QString my_variable("almafa");
qDebug() << my_variable;
```

Before calling the `<<` operator I expect that either `rsi` or `rdi` to contain the address of `my_variable`. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
   0x0000000000400aca <+100>:    lea    -0x60(%rbp),%rdx
   0x0000000000400ace <+104>:    lea    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400ad2 <+108>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x0000000000400ad5 <+111>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400ad8 <+114>:    callq  0x400d40 <QDebug::operator<<(QString const&)>
```

`strings a.out | grep my_variable` returns `my_variable`, so it is present in the executable. Is it somehow possible to ask `gdb` (or any other linux debugger) what is the variable name which belongs to a given address?
`my_variable` is recognized by `gdb` since command `print my_variable` is working.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying amritanshu's answer using the following code:

```
int z;
int main() 
{
    int x;
    x = 5;
    z = 6;
    return 0; 
}
```

Please note that z is a global variable and x is a local variable.  I ran the program in gdb, paused execution of the program at the line **x = 5**. When I used the command

```
info address z
```

I got the following response:

```
Symbol "z" is static storage at address 0x601030.
```

And when I typed:

```
info symbol 0x601030
```

GDB displayed:

```
z in section .bss
```

So, the **info symbol address** command worked for me when examining a global variable.  But, I wasn't able to do the same thing for the local variable **x**.  I determined the address of **x** using the following command:

```
print &x
```

When I used the address that was displayed in the **info symbol** command, GDB displayed

```
No symbol matches ...
```

So, it may depend on whether the address your examining is used for a global or local variable.  As a workaround, you can try using the command [info locals](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Frame-Info.html#Frame-Info), and then use the **print &*variable*** command on each local variable that is displayed.

GDB documentation on the info commands related to examining the symbol table can be found at [Examining the Symbol Table](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html#Symbols).

Answer (score 0):

To identify the nearest symbol for a given address you can try "info" command:

info symbol address